# react_on_rails-> Is a directory @ io_fread - app/assets/webpack/

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs

I try prerender my component but the application throw this error:

```
Is a directory @ io_fread - app/assets/webpack/
```

How i can config the gem to use server render with react_on_rails gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask in repository and the owner says -> https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/issues/460#issuecomment-228181485